# Unable to change checkbox to read only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a table with inline row creation i.e. you click on a **add row** button and it creates an editable row to put data in, and save it via a button once done.

When I click on the save button the **name** property is changed to `read-only` but the checkbox not, how should I do that ?
I tried with the following code without success.

```
<td><input id="btnsubmit" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" /></td><td></tr>';

        function addRow() {
            if ($('#btnsubmit').length == 0) {

                jQuery(html).prependTo('#data-table');

                $('#btnsubmit').click(function () {

                    $('input').attr('readonly', true);

    //I try with this
      $('input[type=checkbox]').attr('readonly', true);

    //also with this


    $('#checkBox1').attr('readonly', true);
                });

            }
        }


 var html = '<tr><td>@Html.TextBox("name")</td><td>@Html.CheckBox("checkBox1")</td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Updated the jsfiddle with your selector type. It works just fine. http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/y26tL/1/

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").attr('disabled', 'true');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Grimbode/y26tL/

```
var check = document.getElementById('check');
check.disabled = true;
```

Simply disable it. :P

JQuery version:

```
$('#check').attr('disabled', 'true');
```

Comment: Thanks Grimbode but its not working any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: The jsfiddle works, you probably have an issue with your selector. Also, try wrapping your script in a $(document).ready(function(){});

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make a checkbox `readonly` as this only for fields that you change their values, and with checkbox you only check them on or off.

So other option could be disable your checkbox .

If you really wish to make it 'readonly' you can do this like that :

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return false"/>
```

Comment: where should I put this code?and how should I connect it to my check box (which was provided as var..

Comment: you could write something like :  $('#checkBox1').click(function() { return false; } );

Comment: Thanks Jony but I try it and its not working...,I want that when I click on buttons submit like the name property the check box will be disabled...

Comment: I believe the OP is asking how to change the checkbox into a disabled state AFTER edits have been made.  Both of these approaches will cause the button to be disabled period.  $('#checkBox1').prop("disabled", true); would work better in this case

Comment: This is fragile: you need to keep a reference to the event handler in order to attach/detach it more than one time.

Answer (score 1):

For checkboxes, the equivalent to a `readonly` attribute is `disabled`. You can set it in pretty much the same way:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").attr("disabled", true);
```

Ed: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/n2zkt/)

Comment: Thanks but try it and its not working ...any other idea?do I need to put and ID in type = ?

Comment: @JeanTehhe Yeah, if you have an id, eg. `$("#checkBox1")`. The attribute itself is valid, double-check the rest of the stuff. See the edit for a fiddle

Comment: @JeanTehhe Oof, sorry, didn't notice the selector was actually invalid... Have to be careful with the quotes with jQuery selectors

Comment: Thanks again BLGT for the support but its not working either,any idea what could be the reason?

Comment: @JeanTehhe The problem is likely elsewhere in your code. Not exactly sure how the dom insertions are handled, where `addRow` is called, etc., provide more details and we'll see if we can help.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Prop() also to disable checkbox.

```
$( "input[type='checkbox']" ).prop({
disabled: true
});
```

Check this

http://api.jquery.com/prop/